# How to pass value/Record id from <ui: button> to controller.js -Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am trying to pass the value/id of record on clicking of button to contoller.js. But Iam not able to get the value in contoller. Any inputs how the value can be passed and retreived in controller.js. Below is the piece of code Iam using currently.

**Piece of component code**

```
{<ui:button aura:data-id="{!account.acc.ContentDocumentId}" buttonTitle="Release Lock" disabled="{!!account.acc.visu__Locked__c}"  class="button" label="Release Lock" press="{!c.Releaselock}"/>}
```

**Controller.js***

```
 Releaselock : function (component, event, helper){     

       var id = event.target.getAttribute("data-id");
      alert(id);

  }
```

Thanks in Advance..

Br
Visu

Comment: Please look at this post: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97509/how-to-use-custom-html-pass-through-attributes-in-lightning-components. Consider using attributes to hold your data, or you can try to use aura:html as suggested in post.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put the id on the aura:id attribute and do event.getSource().getLocalId() ?

**Component**

```
<ui:button aura:id="{!account.acc.ContentDocumentId}" buttonTitle="Release Lock" disabled="{!!account.acc.visu__Locked__c}"  class="button" label="Release Lock" press="{!c.Releaselock}"/>
```

**Controller**

```
Releaselock : function (component, event, helper){     
   var id = event.getSource().getLocalId();
   alert(id);
}
```

Comment: Edited my answer to include some code...